# Adding a django model instance without a form -> button only

Tags: python, html, django, model

i'd like to add a model instance without using a form.

My goal is to adding a instance to a model that contains the current time and the authenticated user name.

So far i have the model:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Zeit(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

And the view (pretty much empty because i tried adding through a model.form):

```
@login_required
def stamper_login(request):
    #form = ZeitForm(request.POST or None)
    print(request.POST)
    context = {
    }
    return render(request, 'stamper_login.html', context)
```

How can i configure the template and the view in a way that will make it possible to send the data to the view?

TY for any help =)

Comment: Ajax on button click sending a POST/GET call to the view and then using `request.user` to create the record.

Comment: Like with $.post(URL,data,callback);?
What data will i send if there is no form?

Comment: Added code in my answer below.

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, all i needed was the following. It will send an empty POST request to the view, which then creates an instance with the currently logged in user. No Ajax required for my usecase, but i will look into it nonetheless.

### Template:

```
<form method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
<button type="submit">Click Me!</button>
```

### View:

```
@login_required
def stamper_login(request):

#form = ZeitForm(request.POST or None)
if request.method == 'POST':
    instance = Zeit(user=request.user)
    instance.save()
    print(instance)
    print(instance.user)
    print(request.POST)
context = {
}

return render(request, 'stamper_login.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0):

Barebones code:

Template. I'm not writing the HTML for this, but I have written the basic Jquery part of it

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#button').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'path/to/your/view',
            method: 'POST'
        }).done(function(){
            //Do something
        })
    })
})
```

Views.py

```
# Assuming the user is already logged in but you can write some code to handle anonymous users
def handle_ajax(request):
    # I've not written code to handle anonymous users
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    zeit = Zeit(user=user) 
    zeit.save()
```